# PHP exec() fails silently - probably memory limit issue

Tags: php, exec, memory-limit

I've got a problem with executing PHP script from another using exec().

I need to execute some PHP script from another (both works in CLI):

```
exec("php /some/path/script.php 2>&1", $output);
echo print_r($output, true);
```

If I invoke my script with this code only (there's no other processing in the same method), everything works correctly. But when I put it at the end of the long running method which consumes a lot of RAM (memory_get_usage() tells that is a bit more than 4 GB just before exec() above), exec() fails silently and echo shows only:

```
array(
)
```

The server I'm using has 6 GB RAM available.

Is it a memory limit issue? PHP memory_limit is set to -1, but I think it reaches other limit. How could I fix/change it?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: have you checked if your script hits execution time limit? normally it is set to 30 secs.

Comment: @bansi, sure, execution time limit is disabled on the server.